# How to get jQuery object from array of matched elements

Tags: jquery

I'm still learning jQuery and am wondering the best way to do this.

I know that when you search for matching elements like this:

```
$('.class'),
```

you get a jQuery object which acts like an array of DOM elements. The question is how to access one of these elements as a jQuery object itself so that I can modify its css.

Right now I'm doing it like so:

```
$($('.class')[0]).css('color', 'red')
```

Is this the idiomatic/proper way in jQuery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to collect a single node as a jQuery Object,

or, `.get()` as a DOM Object.

For example:

```
   //Gets the second index
   $('.class').eq(1).css( 'color', 'red' );
```

or

```
   //Gets the second index as a DOM node
   $('.class').get(1).style.color = 'red';
```